# How do I rotate photos in QPixmap?

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

[image]

[image]

Marked a needle on the speedometer.

```
// 이미지 출력
QPixmap pix("C:\\Users\\WORK002\\Desktop\\speedmeter.png");
QPixmap pix2("C:\\Users\\WORK002\\Desktop\\pointer.png");
QPixmap pointer = pix2.scaled(300, 300);


scene.addPixmap(pix);
scene.addPixmap(pointer);
ui-> graphicsView ->setScene(&scene);
ui-> graphicsView ->show();
```

[image]

I want rotate and reposition.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to mess with the `QPixmap`, you can manipulate the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`  returned by `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap`:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmap_item = scene.addPixmap(pix);
```

To set the position, you can use [`QGraphicsItem::setPos`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos).

To set the rotation, first set the transform origin point with [`QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint),(this will set the point around which your item will be rotated) and then set the rotation with [`QGraphicsItem::setRotation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation):

```
pixmap_item->setPos(50, 0);
pixmap_item->setTransformOriginPoint(pixmap_item->boundingRect().center());
pixmap_item->setRotation(90);
```

You will have to set the correct values yourself, but this should lead you in the right way.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it thanks to you. But positioning, I used "setPos"

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, it should be `setPos` not `setPosition`.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [`QPixmap::transformed()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#transformed)

```
QPixmap QPixmap::transformed(const QTransform &transform, Qt::TransformationMode mode = Qt::FastTransformation) const
```

The specification can be given through the `QTransform` object:

- `rotate()` for rotation
- `translate()` for reposition

Answer (score 2):

may this one can help:

```
//Please note this method takes 2 mseg to finish for a 20x20 pixmap.
QPixmap rotatedPixmap(m_pixOriginal.size());
rotatedPixmap.fill(QColor::fromRgb(0, 0, 0, 0)); //the new pixmap must be transparent.

QPainter* p = new QPainter(&rotatedPixmap);
QSize size = m_pxOriginal.size();
p->translate(size.height()/2,size.height()/2);
p->rotate(m_iAngle);
p->translate(-size.height()/2,-size.height()/2);
p->drawPixmap(0, 0, m_pxOriginal);
p->end();
delete p;
m_pxItem->setPixmap(rotatedPixmap);
```

copied from:
[Read this forum thread](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37098-Rotating-pixmap)